# zsh - Is it possible to run he same command twice with slight modifications?

Tags: bash, zsh

I would like to know if there is a zsh pattern (or bash command) for running the same command in multiple versions, eg.:

```bsh
somelongcommandwithargs {a, b} furtherargs # Some magic syntax represented with {a, b}
```

That would result in zsh running the following commands consequitively:

```bsh
somelongcommandwithargs a furtherargs
somelongcommandwithargs b furtherarg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
eval 'somelongcommandwithargs '{a, b}' furtherargs; '
```

This works with anything, **as long as you make sure your `eval` string ends in `;`** (or whatever else you need to terminate your command). For example:

```
$ touch test
$ echo aaa >> test && echo bbb >> test && eval 'sed -i "" '{s/aaa/ccc/g,s/bbb/ddd/g}' test; '
$ cat test
ccc
ddd
```

Comment: I tried, this does not work:
`echo aaa >> test && echo bb >> test && eval 'sed -i "" '{s/aaa/ccc/g,s/bbb/ddd/g}' test'`

Comment: The reason why your example works is because {a,b} is the pattern to substitute similar strings into the same command, and touch excepts multiple arguments. Your code gives the same result as `touch a-xx b-xx;` instead of what you cited.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You need to add a semicolon to the end of your eval string, like this: `echo aaa >> test && echo bbb >> test && eval 'sed -i "" '{s/aaa/ccc/g,s/bbb/ddd/g}' test; '`

Comment: I updated my answer with this new example.